# What's wrong with fitting room two?

Tags: kingsman-the-secret-service

In *Kingsman: The Secret Service* the following line is used by his superior when the new recruit is about to get his first bespoke fitted suit:

> One does not use fitting room two when one is popping one's cherry.

OK, so the second fitting room is probably not as luxuriously appointed as the first, but is that the only reason Harry doesn't want Eggsy to pop his bespoke suit cherry in there?

Comment: don't have any resources to back this up, but I'd assume it is purely a tradition to use the main or most important fitting room for your first time because it's a special event.

Answer (score 1):

As I remember it fitting room 1 was the room with the long tunnel going down while fitting room 2 had all the gadgets. This doesn't quite answer the question but I would assume it makes fitting room 1 more important. It being his cherry and all.

Comment: Welcome to Movies & TV! Hope you're enjoying it here. However, this particular comment would be better suited for, well, the comments directly on a post (in this case, the question itself), as it is not a full answer in and of itself (given that you're not sure, and that you're currently unable to provide much backup for or to flesh out your answer). (That said, thanks for the thoughtful speculation - it's just currently in the wrong place.)